# Неверная кодировка MySQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Выводит непонятные символы, не могу понять где и как нужно менять кодировку.

Сейчас всё находится в стандартной кодировке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте в `url` явно задать кодировку: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`.

Comment: При создании БД какую кодировку использовали? `utf8_general_ci` или другую?

Comment: При создании БД использовалась стандартная кодировка, т.е я её ни как не указал.

Comment: А если запустить программу из консоли, а не в IDE? Та же проблема?

Comment: Да, та же проблема.